# Authenticate into asp.net app from a winforms app

Tags: asp.net, winforms, authentication

We have 2 applications - 1 windows and 1 web (asp.net). Winforms runs on the customer's machine where as the website is hosted within our company. The winforms has a link which opens the web app in a browser window. The web app is secured so the login page is shown. The username and password is the same as the windows app login. How do I auto-login to the web app so the user will not see the login screen?

The web app uses FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie to create an encrypted cookie on the user's machine. How do I create the same from the winforms app so the user will not see the login screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting into ASP.net.  ASP.net basically writes a web page at run time and serves it thru HTTP.  I think that what you could do would be to write some code that saves a web page on the user's machine.  The page could contain code to push a cookie into the browser (indicating a successful logon) and then redirect the user to your (presumably) secure web site.

Let us know how it works out for you.